# How to get alert notification of my Item sells by subscription to eBay

Tags: api, ebay-api

I am new to programming and API. I want to make a little python bot that parses notifications about item selling. So I found this article: https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/features-guide/default.html#notifications/notifications.html, which tells me that I can subscribe to eBay notification; however, my application should have the capability to receive SOAP requests. So, do I need to develop smth like a SOAP server to be able to receive alerts which tell me that my item has been sold? Maybe you could give some advice to a newbie how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a full SOAP server.
For Platform Notifications, you just need to create a simple listener that can listen to input messages (ItemSold, FixedPriceTransation or EndOfAuction, and AuctionCheckoutComplete notifications. You can choose one of these) in XML/SOAP format from eBay's platform and return a simple "200 OK" response.
A good practice is also to check the Notification Signature.

Also, don't mess up the Notification API and Platform Notifications.

[More about eBay Platform Notifications and signature](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/platform-notifications-landing.html)